# I get an error in this code using "of" in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I am writing a code and i get an error while running the simulation. The error is this:

```
 "You can only use the operator > on two numbers, two strings, or two agents
    of the same type, but can not be used on a list and a number"
```

And the code that i am using is this:

```
   globals
 [
   colors
   ]

  turtles-own
  [
 payoff
  ]

  to setup
  clear-all
  set colors [red green blue]
  create-turtles number
  [
  set color item (who mod 3) (colors)
 setxy random-xcor random-ycor
   ]
  reset-ticks
   end

     to go
    move
    play-piedra
   play-papel
   play-tijeras
    ask turtles [rock]
   ask turtles [papel]
   ask turtles [tijeras]
    end

    to rock
     if [payoff] of turtles with [color = red] > 0
     [set color red]
     if [payoff] of turtles with [color = red] < 0
      [set color green]
      end
```

There is more code but its too long. I think that the problem is that payoff must be in a reporter context but im not sure.

Comment: What is the intent behind the code in the `rock` procedure? What do you want it to do?

Answer (score 4):

`[payoff] of turtles with [color = red]` reports a *list* of payoffs: the payoffs of all the red turtles. You're trying to compare that list with the number `0`, and that makes NetLogo confused.

The [`of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#of) primitive is admittedly a bit confusing because it can work with either a single agent (in which case it reports a value) or an agentset (in which case it reports a list).

The way to fix this will vary depending on what you're trying to do.

- Do you want a [`sum`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sum) of the red turtle payoffs?

  `if sum [payoff] of turtles with [color = red] > 0`
- Do you want to check if *at least one* red turtle has a payoff greater than `0`? In that case, use [`any?`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#any):

  `if any? turtles with [ color = red and payoff > 0 ]`
- Do you want to check if *all* red turtles have a payoff greater than `0`? In that case, use [`all?`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#all):

  `if all? turtles with [ color = red ] [ payoff > 0 ]`
- Are you sure that there is only one red turtle and you only want the payoff for that one? Use [`one-of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#one-of):

  `if [ payoff ] of one-of turtles with [color = red] > 0`

In any case, you will need to make sure you compare values of the same type (e.g., two numbers...)